# what to input in html2image google api in imageGenerator.setSize(Dimension dimension)

Tags: java, html, image, api, google-api

imageGenerator.setSize(dimension);

What to input in the dimension argument,
I tried imageGenerator.setSize(1024,1024) BUT IT'S NOT CORRECT.

Also I want to improve the quality of image , how to do it?
[Reference to the api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-html2image/)

Comment: I tried to reorganise the post

Answer (score 0):

Why not giving the function what it needs?

```
new Dimension(1024, 1024);
```

Something like:

```
imageGenerator.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 1024));
```

Comment: Yay! The image is generated but not exactly the size I wanted, it's generating the same whatever you give the dimension. It's like some small image is pasted on while paper. How can i crop the white background from that generated image?

Comment: Your first question is answered. Maybe you can post a second question with more code. Add a link in the comments to allow me to follow